# How to check success of SELECT query that has no output

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to check to see if the query was successful to process the results, and if not, skip the processing.

SQL Server 2019

This is a larger piece of my code.

Edit: Revised code for clarification, added output.

```
CREATE TABLE #record_changes (
    [id]     int,
    [cID]    varchar(255),
    [fname]  varchar(255),
    [newVal] varchar(255)
);

INSERT INTO #record_changes VALUES 
(1, '00001', 'first_name', 'Sean'),
(2, '00001', 'city', 'Columbus'),
(3, '00001', 'state', 'OH'),
(5, '00604', 'address_1', '123 Acme St'),
(6, '00811', 'address_1', 'PO Box 1234'),
(12,'00074', 'first_name', 'John'),
(13,'00074', 'last_name', 'Doe');


DECLARE
    @max    int = 0,      @cnt    int = 1,
    @cid    varchar(25),  @fname  varchar(255),  @newval    varchar(255), 
    @table  varchar(255), @sql    nvarchar(max);

SET @table = '[custdat]';
SELECT @max = MAX([id]) FROM #record_changes;

PRINT @table;
PRINT @max;

WHILE (@cnt <= @max)
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        @cid = [cID],
        @fname = [fName],
        @newval = [newVal]
      FROM #record_changes
      WHERE [id] = @cnt

    PRINT @cnt    
    PRINT 'cID: ' + @cid
    PRINT 'fName: ' + @fname
    PRINT 'newVal: ' + @newval
    PRINT 'RowCount: ' + CAST( @@ROWCOUNT as varchar(10) )
    
    IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = 'UPDATE ' + @table + ' SET [' + @fname + '] = ''' + @newval + ''' WHERE [CustomerID] = ''' + @cid + ''''
        PRINT @sql
    END

    SET @cid = ''
    SET @fname = ''
    SET @newval = ''
    SET @cnt = @cnt + 1
END
```

Here is the results of the above bit of code.  Note that RowCount is 0, but it prints the variables, so we know the query was successful.

```
[custdat]
13
1
cID: 00001
fName: first_name
newVal: Sean
RowCount: 0
2
cID: 00001
fName: city
newVal: Columbus
RowCount: 0
3
cID: 00001
fName: state
newVal: OH
RowCount: 0
4
cID: 
fName: 
newVal: 
RowCount: 0
5
cID: 00604
fName: address_1
newVal: 123 Acme St
RowCount: 0
6
cID: 00811
fName: address_1
newVal: PO Box 1234
RowCount: 0
7
cID: 
fName: 
newVal: 
RowCount: 0
8
cID: 
fName: 
newVal: 
RowCount: 0
9
cID: 
fName: 
newVal: 
RowCount: 0
10
cID: 
fName: 
newVal: 
RowCount: 0
11
cID: 
fName: 
newVal: 
RowCount: 0
12
cID: 00074
fName: first_name
newVal: John
RowCount: 0
13
cID: 00074
fName: last_name
newVal: Doe
RowCount: 0
```

Since it is not actually returning any results @@ROWCOUNT = 0, so it doesn't work for my IF statement.  I also tried
IF EXISTS( SELECT @cid = [cID]... ) but that didn't work either.

Comment: @@ROWCOUNT holds the number of records affected by the last SQL statement run, in your case the SELECT statement. Why do you think it doesn’t work - if you just run the SELECT statement does it return any records?

Comment: I'm curious why you need to check if a query is successful. Could you not simply try to parse a row out of the dataset and if there are none, move on? I would expect if it was unsuccessful it would probably throw an exception or return zero rows.

Comment: @NickW The processing part is simplified for my example, there is quite a bit that is being done and I don't want it to run if it doesn't need to.  Since the select it just assigning values it doesn't return anything so @@ROWCOUNT = 0  There are gaps in the ids so as I loop through the ids I don't want it to error as it tries to run blank queries or anything like that.

Comment: Is this all happening within some kind of loop?  How are you getting the value for @cnt - is it just an incrementing value?  Your EXISTS( check may not be working because you'd need to remove the variable assignment when doing the EXISTS( check .... what I mean is, try IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #record_changes WHERE [id] = @cnt), and you should then have an accurate check on whether a record (or more) exists

Comment: It's always helpful to discern between "it doesn't work", as in it doesn't produce the result that you expect, vs. "it doesn't work" because there's an error message.  If you really are trying to run EXISTS( SELECT @cid = [cID], etc. .... then you would most certainly be getting an error message.  As opposed to you saying that @@ROWCOUNT doesn't work

Comment: By the way, I ran a small test of my own on SQL 2019.  If I declare a variable, and then do a SELECT @variable = [x] FROM myTable WHERE [y] = @value; - if there is a row in "myTable" where [y] matches the criteria, then @@ROWCOUNT is equal to 1 immediately after the statement.  If there is no row in "myTable" that matches the criteria, then @@ROWCOUNT is equal to zero.  Someone else could validate that this is definitely the case, but it does appear @@ROWCOUNT should work for you, in your particular scenario

Comment: Please don't take this as an insult but this code seems awful. Of course, I don't know the requirements or if it's a legacy code you have to maintain, but from what You've shown in the question and written in the comments (looping in SQL is almost never the correct way to go about things) - I would suggest taking a step back and re-think your process, perhaps even your database design (based on the dynamic sql you've shared).

Comment: Or at least use a cursor and not soem sort of pseudo cursor loop

Comment: @Craig  Updated question with better code and output.

Comment: @ZoharPeled It's probably due to my programming background that I like loops.  Not a fan off Cursor for looping.  It's confusing and not friendly and I've had issues trying to get it working with the way the data I had was structured.  MS maintains WHILE loops for flow control, so it is a valid option.

Comment: OMG, I figured it out and I feel incredibly stupid right now.  I always had a PRINT after the select to verify it was successful and see what was pulled/how it was set.  The PRINT negated the @@ROWCOUNT value.  if I remove the PRINT statements it works as expected.

Comment: @siggemannen using a cursor is still looping over the data. SQL's strong suit is working on sets of data, not on individual records. Even worst is the usage of dynamic SQL which suggest a really bad database design (having multiple tables for storing data which is basically the same is a clear sign of a bad database design) - but that's only hinted by the code of the question so it's harder to tell if that's really the case here.

Comment: @Dizzy49 - we live and learn!

Comment: @ZoharPeled It's utility code.  It will be used on multiple databases where the data is the same but the field name may be different.  So instead of doing a Find/Replace every time I use dynamic SQL to feed the info in.  Again, maybe it's the programming background, I'm all about code re-usability.

Comment: @Dizzy49 in that case, it seems more reasonable.